# The form on the "Ask Question" page is filled with a question which I've already asked

Tags: support, asking-questions, user-interface

I was going to ask a question but when I've clicked on the "Ask Question" tab, the form was already filled with a question I've asked a few days ago. Even refreshing doesn't empty the form.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Can you click the discard link next to the Post Your Question button?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: Damn buggy computer saved my work without even asking!

Comment: @CodyGray I don't get why would I need a draft of a question I've already posted... Discarding the question works.

Comment: Also, I've just discarded the draft, left the page, got an alert about saving my modification, selected "no", come back to the ask question page and I see the title of the old question with no body. If this is a new feature it seems a little buggy to me...

Comment: @CodyGray I know right! In fact, I wish my computer would just delete my work whenever is shutdown.

Comment: Windows 10 shut down on me yesterday to automatically install an update I had not given permission for it to install. I was in the middle of a complex debugging session, and had many applications open. Indeed, it lost all of my work. If you enjoy this behavior, @Mr.goosberry, you should definitely install Windows 10.

Comment: @CodyGray Absolutely! I just love it when window says to me; _"screw you!, I'm gonna install some updates , even thought you explicitly told me no, which causes you to lose  hours of work!"_

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The form on the "Ask Question" page automatically saves your input. This feature was designed to prevent losing your work, for example when you accidentally close the page.

This shouldn't happen if you already posted that question, and it might be a bug, but anyway I don't think it's worth fixing. You can always click the "discard" link next to the "Post Your Question" button.

[image]

Comment: Better if it saves too much for too long than the opposite.