# Why do I see my previous question when I click on Ask question?

Tags: bug, asking-questions, meta, draft

I asked a question 2 days ago which got an answer. Today I wanted to ask another question so I clicked on the "Ask question" button but I was surprised when I got this screen.

[image: Issue]

You can see my old question is already in the form. Is there a bug in Meta that it will store the last question and will put like you are editing or something else?

**UPDATED**

As gothdo mentioned that this is dupe of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333249/the-form-on-the-ask-question-page-is-filled-with-a-question-which-ive-already) but as we all can see gothdo is saying that if you will post your question then it should not be there but i can still see this so should we tell the SO team to fix it? well he mentioned that its not worth fixing it but i think its not better to live with issue rather then to remove it when its not big deal, right?

Comment: but not till you save as draft, right?

Comment: and this never happen before.

Comment: well as i mentioned, i have post the question 2 days ago and it got answer(or yours) then i am sure its not draft, right?

Comment: @Glorfindel: And he's saying that the draft *wasn't* discarded after he posted his previous question. *That's* the bug he's referring to.

Comment: @BoltClock yes that's the question of mine.

Comment: All I can say is that it's stored server-side ...

Comment: @Gothdo please check my updated question. Thank you

Comment: ark Anthon @code gray..can you all please check that answer and tell me where is solution rather then saying leave that bug??

Comment: @Leothelion why do you expect another regular user to have more information than you can collect? Realistically non-fatal bug that shows up once in tens thousand cases is rarely worth fixing - I'm not sure what else you can do to get it at least looked at by SE team in addition to asking this question.

Comment: Same thing I just noted