# Saving question/answers as drafts

Tags: feature-request

I wonder if this will be a good addition to the site.
Let's say that a given user has written a long question, with great detail and the power of his/her's PC went off. well, you guessed it. you get a pissed off person that has to write the very long question. is it possible so make this feature of auto save the post, every 30 seconds or so that they can return to it later on? I think i will be very good, especially in a technical site where people are posting photos, solutions and what not. 
Thanks.

Comment: [Already happens](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333249/the-form-on-the-ask-question-page-is-filled-with-a-question-which-ive-already). And please don't post photos on a technical site.

Comment: See this too http://stackapps.com/questions/2373/add-draft-save-links